# Outputting JSON with angle brackets in browser

Tags: json, browser

Currently I'm working on a small webservice which outputs JSON to the client. For testing purposes I let the JSON output on my browser (Firefox 20). Within the JSON I use tags for declaring text in different languages but it seems that this causes some trouble as my browser filters the start tag.

I guess the browsers (I also tried it on Chrome and Opera) think that the tags are HTML and try to handle it. So I put the JSON code in CODE-Tags and PRE-Tags as well but the result is always the same.

In other words, what I get:

```
"description":"Bild 1<\/de>Image 1<\/en>\u5199\u771f\u7b2c\u4e00<\/jp>"
```

What I want:

```
"description":"<de>Bild 1<\/de><en>Image 1<\/en><jp>\u5199\u771f\u7b2c\u4e00<\/jp>"
```

Important: The output is what it have to be (says my debugger), it's just how the browser shows it. Is there a possibility to let the browsers ignore the tags or do I have to use "& lt;" and "& gt;"? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Escaping XML might seem like the immediate solution, but it is not. It will break your original webservice.

Please recheck if you are sending the below header in the response:

```
Content-Type: application/json
```

The above header would make the browsers interpret the response as a JSON (and not HTML)

Comment: "header('Content-Type: application/json');" did it. Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, try using escape characters [XML Escape characters](http://xmmssc-www.star.le.ac.uk/SAS/xmmsas_20070308_1802/doc/param/node24.html)